# Syncfusion Bar Chart Legend shape does not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I've been trying to customize the legend shape of Syncfusion chart however it doesn't give any changes. There are no error message in the code. I wondered what I missed in the code. Here's my codes

```html
CSHTML FILE

<div class="box box-default">
<div class="box-body">
            @Html.EJS().Chart("container").Series(
            sr =>
           {
            sr.XName("Name").YName("Loan").Name("Loan Risk").Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();
            sr.XName("Name").YName("Score").Name("Loan Score").Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();
            sr.Marker(mr => mr.DataLabel(dl => dl.Visible(true).Position(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LabelPosition.Top).Font(ff => ff.FontWeight("600").Color("#ffffff")))).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Name("Users").Add();
                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                    
            }).PrimaryYAxis(px => px.LabelFormat("p1").LabelStyle(ls => ls.Color("#21130d")).LineStyle(ls => ls.Width(0)).MajorTickLines(mg => mg.Width(0))
            .MajorGridLines(mg => mg.Width(0))
            ).PrimaryXAxis(px => px.LabelIntersectAction(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LabelIntersectAction.Hide).Interval(1)
            .ValueType(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ValueType.Category).MajorGridLines(mg => mg.Width(0))).Tooltip(tt => tt.Enable(true)
            ).ChartArea(area => area.Border(br => br.Color("transparent"))
            ).LegendSettings(lg => lg.Visible(true).Shape(ChartShape.Hexagon)).Title("Pre - Funding Audit Report").Render()

</div>
</div>
```

I used the Shape(ChartShape.Hexagon) method to call the Shape of the legend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suggest you to use Fill property to change the series color. You can add percentage for y axis labels using LabelFormat property and using LegendShape property, you can change the legend icon. Please check with below snippet and screenshot.

```
@Html.EJS().Chart("container").Series(
sr =>
{
    sr.Fill("orange").ColumnSpacing(0.1).Marker(mr => mr.DataLabel(dl => 
    dl.Visible(true))).          
    LegendShape(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LegendShape.Rectangle).Add();
}).PrimaryXAxis(
    xAxis => {        
    xAxis.MajorTickLines(mt=>mt.Width(0)).MajorGridLines(mg=>mg.Width(0));  })
.PrimaryYAxis(
    yAxis=>yAxis.LineStyle(ls=>ls.Width(0)).MajorTickLines(mt => 
    mt.Width(0)).MajorGridLines(mg => mg.Width(0)).LabelFormat("{value}%"))
.LegendSettings(ls=>ls.ShapeHeight(5).ShapeWidth(20))
.Render()
```

[image: Legend Shape]

Sample : https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SeriesFill-1342476938.zip

UG :

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/documentation/chart/axis-customization/
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/documentation/chart/chart-annotations/

Note : If you want to add custom legend in chart, you can use Annotations property.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

When we noticed the provided code snippet, we came to know that you have set the shape for the legend in legend Settings. We need to set the legend shape by setting the shape to the LegendShape property in the series of the Chart. We have created a simple MVC application to demonstrate the same and it can be downloaded from the below link.

Sample link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ChartLegendShape824569931

Please find the below link for the shapes that are available for the legend in Charts for your reference.

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/aspnetcore-js2/Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LegendShape.html

Code Snippet:

Series.LegendShape(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LegendShape.Pentagon).

Kindly, revert us if you have any concerns.

Regards,
Swetha